# how to implement rete algorithm in php?

Tags: php, algorithm, rete

My final project is to implement rete algorithm in an expert system

I understand that rete algorithm is using working memory, I'm very confused how to implement it in the coding

I don't understand the term working memory in php

Is is the same as session or should I use shmop?

any help or suggestion is highly appreciated

thanks

Comment: no, it's just memory. And the Rete algorithm says nothing about which kind of memory it should use, it just makes far more sense to do it in working memory because that's fastest, and in PHP's case gives you a hilariously low limit in terms of what you can do (due to having only 12MBish before PHP crashes over an out of memory error, unless you cheat and force it to use more).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: which is this 12MB-ish OOM-crash you are speaking of? (1) The default `memory_limit` is 8M before PHP 5.2.0, 16M in PHP 5.2.0, 128M for later versions (2) I'd hardly call consciously upping a memory limit a cheat? Of all the bad things to say about PHP (and there's a lot..), having a memory-limit feature is not one of them IMHO. Or is this somehow related to a specific PHP implementation of a Rete algorithm?

Comment: @Wrikken wow, you took that completely the wrong way. I was pointing out PHP has a memory limit, which means an implementation of the Rete Algorithm has to take that into account, as opposed to when using a general purpose "I have several gigabytes of memory at my disposal" environment like C/C++ - Whether it's 8, 16 or 128, PHP comes with memory restrictions that you need to bear in mind (especially if this has to run "online" somewhere for grading. shared hosting PHP instances rarely ever get more than a few tens of MBs at most)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Ah, check, the words 'crash' ("enforce limits") and 'cheat' ("configure limits") threw me somewhat there :P